# Проверка доступности сайта

Tags: php

Необходимо проверить, доступен ли сайт. Проверяю так, нормальное ли это решение?

```
$port = 80;
$host = 'ya.ru';

$fp = fsockopen($host,$port);
if(!$fp){
//не доступен
} else {
//всё ок
}
```

Comment: Таймаут укажите маленький (< 5 сек) и наверное нормально будет http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: Открытый сокет ещё не обязательно означает работоспособность сайта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cURL-ом решил задачу, тут на форуме пример был, что-то вроде

```
$domain = 'ya.ru';
//инициализация curl
$curlInit = curl_init($domain);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//получение ответа
$response = curl_exec($curlInit);
curl_close($curlInit);
$response = $response ? $response = 'всё ок' : $response = 'недоступен';
echo $response;
```

Answer (score -2):

Открый сокет не поможет, получай контент сайта, и по нему определишь, доступен или нет.

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://ya.ru');
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?